# How to use Apache ZooKeeper with Spring Cloud service discovery and load balancing?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud, service-discovery, microservices

I'm new to Apache ZooKeeper concept to implement the service discovery and load balancing with netflix ribbon client. I seen some examples in github (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper ). Could anyone help me to know how to set-up the ZooKeeper and service discovery implementation on app service instances. I'm very curious to know about this concept.

Thanks in advance..,

Comment: what exactly do you need from zookeeper? If its only service discovery then eureka may be easier.

Comment: @Freakman: Yes you are right. Eureka was easier to implement the service registry and service discovery. But, As per the requirement, i have to use ZooKeeper.

Answer (score 1):

For today (`in March 2018`) you should use `Zookeeper Dependencies`.

- Add dependency `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-discovery`;
- Setting up `Zookeeper Dependencies`

  ```
  spring:
      # your app name
      application.name: app
      cloud.zookeeper:
          discovery:
              root: /path/to/your/dependencies
              enabled: true
          dependencies:
              dependencyOne:
                  # absolute path is /path/to/your/dependencies/dependencyOne
                  path: /dependencyOne
                  loadBalancerType: ROUND_ROBIN
                  required: false
                  stubs: org.springframework:foo:stubs
          dependency.resttemplate.enabled: false
  ```

See more in [spring-cloud docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-zookeeper-dependencies)